# Soft delete and recovery (MySQL, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, soft-delete

I need to be able to delete messages and to restore them until the page is not reloaded. So I have a field 'is_deleted' in my 'messages' table. What I want is to delete these 'deleted' records after it. What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: You'll have to be a bit clearer as to what it is you want to achieve? You want these elements that are marked as deleted to be purged/removed when the user leaves your page? Or do you want a button in your administration panel to purge items marked as deleted?

Comment: How can you want to do something 'until' something does *not* happen(page being reloaded)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your needs, a "purge" button may be what you want or a lot of times people will use a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and set the `is_deleted` to be a Nullable `DATETIME` field, if after x days, it still shows as being deleted, it is automatically deleted from the database.

So if the automatic way appeals to you and you are on linux look at Cron jobs or if on windows Task Scheduler. If you would like an example of the cron, I need to know how frequently you would want the records purged from the system and I will provide you with an example of one.

For example, to run the delete script every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/script/purgeDeleted.php > /dev/null
```

You will still have to write the purgeDeleted.php script, but that is the setup for running a php cli script via a cron job in Linux.